# python, disnake, как исправить ошибку?

Tags: python, discord, disnake

```
@bot.slash_command(name = "монетка", description = "Бросить монетку")
async def монетка(inter, сторона: Option(choices=[OptionChoice(name="сторона", value ="орел"), OptionChoice(name="сторона", value="решка")], description = "Попробуйте угадать какой стороной упадет монетка"):
    randomCoins = ["орел", "решка"]
    random.shuffle(randomCoins)
    randomCoin = random.choice(randomCoins)
    if сторона == randomCoin:
        embedCoinWin = disnake.Embed(title = "Ух! Вы угадали.", description = f"> Ваше предположение: {сторона.value}\n\n> Выпавшая сторона: {randomCoin}")
        await inter.response.send_message(embed=embedCoinWin)
    else:
        embedCoinLose = disnake.Embed(title = "Упс! Вы не угадали.", description = f"> Ваше предположение: {сторона.value}\n\n> Выпавшая сторона: {randomCoin}")
        await inter.response.send_message(embed=embedCoinLose)
```

Сама ошибка

```
init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
    async def монетка(inter, сторона: Option(choices=[OptionChoice(name="сторона", value ="орел"), OptionChoice(name="сторона", value="решка")]) = commands.Param(description = "Попробуйте угадать какой стороной упадет монетка")):
TypeError: init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Comment: отформатируйте код у себя в соответствии с PEP-8, а также НЕ НАЗЫВАЙТЕ переменные русскими буквами. Обязательно надо называть переменные английскими буквами.

Comment: И мне очень сильно кажется, что в вопросе не тот код функции...